# Freemarker PDF/Email template list filter

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I want to make a list of filtered items in Netsuite HTML/email template. Seems that this line of code wont work on it using freemarker.

```
<#assign xs = [1, -2, 3, 4, -5]>
Positives:
<#list xs?filter(x -> x > 0) as x>${x} </#list>
Negatives:
<#list xs?filter(x -> x < 0) as x>${x} </#list>
```

Could you guys give me some insights on how to achieve this? Thank you so much in advance! I'm a beginner and been searching this a lot and unfortunately no luck at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like NetSuite is using FreeMarker v2.3.26 and the `filter` built-in was added in 2.3.29.

Here's one way to do it without `filter`:

```
<#assign xs = [1, -2, 3, 4, -5]>
<#assign xpos = []>
<#assign xneg = []>

<#list xs as x>
    <#if x gt 0>
        <#assign xpos = xpos + [x]>
    <#elseif x lt 0>
        <#assign xneg = xneg + [x]>
    </#if>
</#list>

Positives:
<#list xpos as x>${x} </#list>

Negatives:
<#list xneg as x>${x} </#list>
```

Comment: Note iterating on a list that's the result of lot of concatenated like above can be slow. This kind of concatenation was meant to be used to add together a a few lists, not to build an entire new list from lists of length 1. So, since there's no `?filter` there, you can also put the condition inside the `#list`. However, then things like `#sep`, `?index`, etc., won't work properly.